# How To get reference of the Collapse Tool of Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-architect, treepanel

I am new to ext-js and i have a Tree Panel which has a collapse Tool for collapse/Expand
of panel on click of the collapse tool.
I wanted to know how can i get the reference to that Collapse Tool button present in the
panel's title.
I want to click the collapse tool by using click event so that the panel will collapse/expand.
please help me in finding solution.

**[This is the fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7in)**

```
Ext.define('project.view.navigation', {
extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
alias: 'widget.navigation',

requires: [
    'Ext.tree.View'
],

width: 295,
animCollapse: true,
collapsed: true,
collapsible: true,
title: 'Menu',
titleCollapse: false,
store: 'navigationStore',
rootVisible: false,

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        viewConfig: {

        }
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

I have done it using Sencha Architect 3.0
This Tree Panel is present in the west region of viewport in Border Layout.

The code For main Viewport is as shown below

```
Ext.define('projectName.view.mainView', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

requires: [
    'projectName.view.header',
    'projectName.view.navigation',
    'projectName.view.searchContent',
    'projectName.view.content',
    'projectName.view.footer',
    'Ext.tree.Panel'
],

itemId: 'mainView',
layout: 'border',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;

    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                region: 'center',
                cls: 'mainContainer',
                layout: 'border',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'appHeader',
                        height: 100,
                        region: 'north'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'navigation',
                        region: 'west'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'searchContent',
                        region: 'west'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'content',
                        region: 'center'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'footer',
                        region: 'south'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: Could you please paste the piece of code for your 'Collapse tool button' .

Comment: I have put the code for Tree Panel for which i want collapse Tool.

Comment: [This is the fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/7in)

Answer (score 0):

You can just call the `collapse()` method on the panel itself. Check out the documentation for it:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-collapse

For example, if `panel` was a reference to your tree panel:

```
panel.collapse();
```

This would collapse the panel using the collapse config options you already set in your panel definition.

Comment: The above Tree Panel is present in West Region Of the border layout.   I have used this option the problem is that after collapse, when the Tree Panel is expanded next time it is moving towards right.

Comment: So, does this NOT happen when you click on the collapse arrow? If it still happens then, then your issue is a layout issue, not an issue with how to collapse the panel. In which case, we will need to see the rest of the code for where the panel is nested. A working example in jsfiddle.net would be great.

Comment: I have put the code for main view port.I have also set the property hideCollapseTool: true in Tree Panel.By this the panel collapses/expands on clicking at any place on title.I am doing it in Sencha Architect 3 , but i want to get the reference of that collapse tool and fire click event on that.

Comment: My point is, if the collapse tool is shown, and you click on it, if it collapses and expands in the same way as when you call the `collapse` method, then getting the collapse button is a lot of extra work for nothing. That is why I asked about that.

Comment: Thank you for responding. As you can see in the above main viewport code i have put recently, there are two panels in the west region which have same width.If i click the collapse tool both the panels appear next to each other. Wright now when you click on title the Tree Panel appears over the other panel and if i click the title again it collapses back or when mouse is moved out of Tree panel it collapses which is default behaviour.